# Excel 2010 VBA. Need a dialog to locate a text filename but NOT to open

Tags: file-io, excel-2010

I am looking for a way to use the Windows dialogs from Excel 2010 VBA so that the user can browse for a text file.

Once found the selection will return the filename so that it can then be used to read the file into memory as a string.

I don't want to read it directly into a workbook as I need to then process the file using mid$ etc. and place each character in turn into a worksheet cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Filters.Add "Text files", "*.txt"
    .Show

    For Each Filename In .SelectedItems
        MsgBox Filename
    Next
End With
```